# MySQL - Using special characters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems with using special characters in MySQL.

My code retrive some info from 2 tables to 2 combobox but the problem is that the words with special characters get all messed up.

This is the HTML page with the 2 combobox:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Adicionar Clube</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<form action="adicionarClubeBD.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"id="nome"/><br>
Logo: <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo"/><br>
Telefone: <input type="text" name="telefone"id="telefone"/><br>
Distrito:  <select name="distrito" id="distrito">
                <option value="">Selecione o distrito</option>
                <?php include 'listarDistritos.php'; ?>
            </select> <br> <br>
Localidade: <select name="localidade" id="localidade">
                <option value="">Selecione a localidade</option>
            </select> <br> <br>
Rua: <input type="text" name="rua"id="rua"/><br>
Código Postal: <input type="text" name="codigo_postal"id="codigo_postal"/><br>
<input  type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Guardar">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).on('change','#distrito',function(){
             var val = $(this).val();
             $.ajax({
                   url: 'listarLocalidades.php',
                   data: {distrito:val},
                   type: 'GET',
                   dataType: 'html',
                   success: function(result){
                        $('#localidade').html();  
                        $('#localidade').html(result); 
                   }
              });
       });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the database:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.3.9
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Máquina: 127.0.0.1
-- Data de Criação: 09-Jun-2014 às 14:43
-- Versão do servidor: 5.1.35
-- versão do PHP: 5.3.5

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Base de Dados: `aluguercampos`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `administrador`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `administrador` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `administrador`
--

INSERT INTO `administrador` (`id`, `nome`, `password`) VALUES
(1, 'admin', 'admin');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `campo`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `descricao` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `id_localidade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rua` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `codigo_postal` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `id_piso` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_coberto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_localidade` (`id_localidade`),
  KEY `id_piso` (`id_piso`),
  KEY `id_coberto` (`id_coberto`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `campo`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `campo_fotos`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campo_fotos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_campo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome_foto` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `caminho_foto` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_campo` (`id_campo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `campo_fotos`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `campo_gestor`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campo_gestor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_gestor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_campo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_gestor` (`id_gestor`),
  KEY `id_campo` (`id_campo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `campo_gestor`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `campo_modalidade`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campo_modalidade` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_campo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_modalidade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_campo` (`id_campo`),
  KEY `id_modalidade` (`id_modalidade`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `campo_modalidade`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `clube`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clube` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `logo` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefone` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `id_localidade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rua` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `codigo_postal` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_localidade` (`id_localidade`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `clube`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `clube_gestor`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clube_gestor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_clube` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_gestor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_clube` (`id_clube`),
  KEY `id_gestor` (`id_gestor`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `clube_gestor`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `coberto`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coberto` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `coberto`
--

INSERT INTO `coberto` (`id`, `nome`) VALUES
(1, 'Sim'),
(2, 'Não');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `disponibilidade_campo`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `disponibilidade_campo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_campo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `n_posicoes_disponiveis` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `n_min_posicoes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_hora_inicio` datetime NOT NULL,
  `data_hora_fim` datetime NOT NULL,
  `preco` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_campo` (`id_campo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `disponibilidade_campo`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `distrito`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `distrito` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `distrito`
--

INSERT INTO `distrito` (`id`, `nome`) VALUES
(1, 'Açores'),
(2, 'Aveiro'),
(3, 'Beja'),
(4, 'Braga'),
(5, 'Bragança'),
(6, 'Castelo Branco'),
(7, 'Coimbra'),
(8, 'Évora'),
(9, 'Faro'),
(10, 'Guarda'),
(11, 'Leiria'),
(12, 'Lisboa'),
(13, 'Madeira'),
(14, 'Portalegre'),
(15, 'Porto'),
(16, 'Santarém'),
(17, 'Setúbal'),
(18, 'Viana do Castelo'),
(19, 'Vila Real'),
(20, 'Viseu');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `gestor`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gestor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `id_localidade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rua` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `codigo_postal` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `foto` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_localidade` (`id_localidade`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `gestor`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `localidade`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `localidade` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_distrito` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_distrito` (`id_distrito`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=427 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `localidade`
--

INSERT INTO `localidade` (`id`, `nome`, `id_distrito`) VALUES
(3, 'Angra do Heroísmo', 1),
(4, 'Calheta', 1),
(5, 'Corvo', 1),
(6, 'Horta', 1),
(7, 'Lagoa', 1),
(8, 'Lajes das Flores', 1),
(9, 'Lajes do Pico', 1),
(10, 'Madalena', 1),
(11, 'Nordeste', 1),
(12, 'Ponta Delgada', 1),
(13, 'Povoação', 1),
(14, 'Ribeira Grande', 1),
(15, 'S. Roque do Pico', 1),
(16, 'Sta. Cruz da Graciosa', 1),
(17, 'Sta. Cruz das Flores', 1),
(18, 'Velas', 1),
(19, 'Vila do Porto', 1),
(20, 'Vila Franca do Campo', 1),
(21, 'Praia da Vitória', 1),
(22, 'Águeda', 2),
(23, 'Albergaria-a-Velha', 2),
(24, 'Anadia', 2),
(25, 'Arouca', 2),
(26, 'Aveiro', 2),
(27, 'Castelo de Paiva', 2),
(28, 'Espinho', 2),
(29, 'Estarreja', 2),
(30, 'Sta. Maria da Feira', 2),
(31, 'Ílhavo', 2),
(32, 'Mealhada', 2),
(33, 'Murtosa', 2),
(34, 'Oliveira de Azemeis', 2),
(35, 'Oliveira do Bairro', 2),
(36, 'Ovar', 2),
(37, 'S. João da Madeira', 2),
(38, 'Sever do Vouga', 2),
(39, 'Vagos', 2),
(40, 'Vale de Cambra', 2),
(41, 'Aljustrel', 3),
(42, 'Almodôvar', 3),
(43, 'Alvito', 3),
(44, 'Barrancos', 3),
(45, 'Beja', 3),
(46, 'Castro Verde', 3),
(47, 'Cuba', 3),
(48, 'Ferreira do Alentejo', 3),
(49, 'Mértola', 3),
(50, 'Moura', 3),
(51, 'Odemira', 3),
(52, 'Ourique', 3),
(53, 'Serpa', 3),
(54, 'Vidigueira', 3),
(70, 'Amares', 4),
(71, 'Barcelos', 4),
(72, 'Braga', 4),
(73, 'Cabeceiras de Basto', 4),
(74, 'Celorico de Basto', 4),
(75, 'Esposende', 4),
(76, 'Fafe', 4),
(77, 'Guimarães', 4),
(78, 'Póvoa de Lanhoso', 4),
(79, 'Terras de Bouro', 4),
(80, 'Vieira do Minho', 4),
(81, 'Vila Nova de Famalicão', 4),
(82, 'Vila Verde', 4),
(83, 'Vizela', 4),
(84, 'Alfândega da Fé', 5),
(85, 'Bragança', 5),
(86, 'Carrazeda de Ansiães', 5),
(87, 'Freixo de Espada à Cinta', 5),
(88, 'Macedo de Caveleiros', 5),
(89, 'Miranda do Douro', 5),
(90, 'Mirandela', 5),
(91, 'Mogadouro', 5),
(92, 'Moncorvo', 5),
(93, 'Vila Flor', 5),
(94, 'Vimioso', 5),
(95, 'Vinhais', 5),
(96, 'Belmonte', 6),
(97, 'Castelo Branco', 6),
(98, 'Covilhã', 6),
(99, 'Fundão', 6),
(100, 'Idanha-a-Nova', 6),
(101, 'Oleiros', 6),
(102, 'Penamacôr', 6),
(103, 'Proença-a-Nova', 6),
(104, 'Sertã', 6),
(105, 'Vila de Rei', 6),
(106, 'Vila Velha de Ródão', 6),
(124, 'Arganil', 7),
(125, 'Cantanhede', 7),
(126, 'Coimbra', 7),
(127, 'Condeixa-a-Nova', 7),
(128, 'Figueira da Foz', 7),
(129, 'Góis', 7),
(130, 'Lousã', 7),
(131, 'Mira', 7),
(132, 'Miranda do Corvo', 7),
(133, 'Montemor-o-Velho', 7),
(134, 'Oliveira do Hospital', 7),
(135, 'Pampilhosa da Serra', 7),
(136, 'Penacova', 7),
(137, 'Penela', 7),
(138, 'Soure', 7),
(139, 'Tábua', 7),
(140, 'Vila Nova de Poiares', 7),
(141, 'Alandroal', 8),
(142, 'Arraiolos', 8),
(143, 'Borba', 8),
(144, 'Estremoz', 8),
(145, 'Évora', 8),
(146, 'Montemor-o-Novo', 8),
(147, 'Mora', 8),
(148, 'Mourão', 8),
(149, 'Portel', 8),
(150, 'Redondo', 8),
(151, 'Reguengos de Monsaraz', 8),
(152, 'Vendas Novas', 8),
(153, 'Viana do Alentejo', 8),
(154, 'Vila Viçosa', 8),
(172, 'Albufeira', 9),
(173, 'Alcoutim', 9),
(174, 'Aljezur', 9),
(175, 'Castro Marim', 9),
(176, 'Faro', 9),
(177, 'Lagoa', 9),
(178, 'Lagos', 9),
(179, 'Loulé', 9),
(180, 'Monchique', 9),
(181, 'Olhão', 9),
(182, 'Portimão', 9),
(183, 'S. Brás de Alportel', 9),
(184, 'Silves', 9),
(185, 'Tavira', 9),
(186, 'Vila do Bispo', 9),
(187, 'Vila Real de Santo António', 9),
(202, 'Aguiar da Beira', 10),
(203, 'Almeida', 10),
(204, 'Celorico da Beira', 10),
(205, 'Figueira de Castelo Rodrigo', 10),
(206, 'Fornos de Algodres', 10),
(207, 'Gouveia', 10),
(208, 'Guarda', 10),
(209, 'Manteigas', 10),
(210, 'Mêda', 10),
(211, 'Pinhel', 10),
(212, 'Sabugal', 10),
(213, 'Seia', 10),
(214, 'Trancoso', 10),
(215, 'Vila Nova de Foz Côa', 10),
(232, 'Alcobaça', 11),
(233, 'Alvaiázere', 11),
(234, 'Ansião', 11),
(235, 'Batalha', 11),
(236, 'Bombarral', 11),
(237, 'Caldas da Rainha', 11),
(238, 'Castanheira de Pera', 11),
(239, 'Figueiró dos Vinhos', 11),
(240, 'Leiria', 11),
(241, 'Marinha Grande', 11),
(242, 'Nazaré', 11),
(243, 'Óbidos', 11),
(244, 'Pedrogão Grande', 11),
(245, 'Peniche', 11),
(246, 'Pombal', 11),
(247, 'Porto de Mós', 11),
(264, 'Alenquer', 12),
(265, 'Amadora', 12),
(266, 'Arruda dos Vinhos', 12),
(267, 'Azambuja', 12),
(268, 'Cadaval', 12),
(269, 'Cascais', 12),
(270, 'Lisboa', 12),
(271, 'Loures', 12),
(272, 'Lourinhã', 12),
(273, 'Mafra', 12),
(274, 'Oeiras', 12),
(275, 'Sintra', 12),
(276, 'Sobral de Monte Agraço', 12),
(277, 'Torres Vedras', 12),
(278, 'Vila Franca de Xira', 12),
(279, 'Odivelas', 12),
(291, 'Calheta', 13),
(292, 'Câmara de Lobos', 13),
(293, 'Funchal', 13),
(294, 'Machico', 13),
(295, 'Ponta do Sol', 13),
(296, 'Porto Moniz', 13),
(297, 'Porto Santo', 13),
(298, 'Ribeira Brava', 13),
(299, 'Sta. Cruz', 13),
(300, 'Santana', 13),
(301, 'S. Vicente', 13),
(302, 'Alter do Chão', 14),
(303, 'Arronches', 14),
(304, 'Avis', 14),
(305, 'Campo Maior', 14),
(306, 'Castelo de Vide', 14),
(307, 'Crato', 14),
(308, 'Elvas', 14),
(309, 'Fronteira', 14),
(310, 'Gavião', 14),
(311, 'Marvão', 14),
(312, 'Monforte', 14),
(313, 'Nisa', 14),
(314, 'Ponte de Sor', 14),
(315, 'Portalegre', 14),
(316, 'Sousel', 14),
(317, 'Amarante', 15),
(318, 'Baião', 15),
(319, 'Felgueiras', 15),
(320, 'Gondomar', 15),
(321, 'Lousada', 15),
(322, 'Maia', 15),
(323, 'Marco de Canaveses', 15),
(324, 'Matosinhos', 15),
(325, 'Paços de Ferreira', 15),
(326, 'Paredes', 15),
(327, 'Penafiel', 15),
(328, 'Porto', 15),
(329, 'Póvoa de Varzim', 15),
(330, 'Santo Tirso', 15),
(331, 'Valongo', 15),
(332, 'Vila do Conde', 15),
(333, 'Vila Nova de Gaia', 15),
(334, 'Trofa', 15),
(335, 'Abrantes', 16),
(336, 'Alcanena', 16),
(337, 'Almeirim', 16),
(338, 'Alpiarça', 16),
(339, 'Benavente', 16),
(340, 'Cartaxo', 16),
(341, 'Chamusca', 16),
(342, 'Constância', 16),
(343, 'Coruche', 16),
(344, 'Entrocamento', 16),
(345, 'Ferreira do Zêzere', 16),
(346, 'Golegã', 16),
(347, 'Mação', 16),
(348, 'Ourém', 16),
(349, 'Rio Maior', 16),
(350, 'Salvaterra de Magos', 16),
(351, 'Santarém', 16),
(352, 'Sardoal', 16),
(353, 'Tomar', 16),
(354, 'Torres Novas', 16),
(355, 'Vila Nova da Barquinha', 16),
(356, 'Alcácer do Sal', 17),
(357, 'Alcochete', 17),
(358, 'Almada', 17),
(359, 'Barreiro', 17),
(360, 'Grândola', 17),
(361, 'Moita', 17),
(362, 'Montijo', 17),
(363, 'Palmela', 17),
(364, 'Santiago do Cacém', 17),
(365, 'Seixal', 17),
(366, 'Sesimbra', 17),
(367, 'Setúbal', 17),
(368, 'Sines', 17),
(379, 'Arcos de Valdevez', 18),
(380, 'Caminha', 18),
(381, 'Melgaço', 18),
(382, 'Monção', 18),
(383, 'Paredes de Coura', 18),
(384, 'Ponte da Barca', 18),
(385, 'Ponte de Lima', 18),
(386, 'Valença', 18),
(387, 'Viana do Castelo', 18),
(388, 'Vila Nova de Cerveira', 18),
(389, 'Alijó', 19),
(390, 'Boticas', 19),
(391, 'Chaves', 19),
(392, 'Mesão Frio', 19),
(393, 'Mondim de Basto', 19),
(394, 'Montalegre', 19),
(395, 'Murça', 19),
(396, 'Peso da Régua', 19),
(397, 'Ribeira de Pena', 19),
(398, 'Sabrosa', 19),
(399, 'Sta. Marta de Penaguião', 19),
(400, 'Valpaços', 19),
(401, 'Vila Pouca de Aguiar', 19),
(402, 'Vila Real', 19),
(403, 'Armamar', 20),
(404, 'Carregal do Sal', 20),
(405, 'Castro Daire', 20),
(406, 'Cinfães', 20),
(407, 'Lamego', 20),
(408, 'Mangualde', 20),
(409, 'Moimenta da Beira', 20),
(410, 'Mortágua', 20),
(411, 'Nelas', 20),
(412, 'Oliveira de Frades', 20),
(413, 'Penalva do Castelo', 20),
(414, 'Penedono', 20),
(415, 'Resende', 20),
(416, 'S. João da Pesqueira', 20),
(417, 'S. Pedro do Sul', 20),
(418, 'Sta. Comba Dão', 20),
(419, 'Sátão', 20),
(420, 'Sernancelhe', 20),
(421, 'Tabuaço', 20),
(422, 'Tarouca', 20),
(423, 'Tondela', 20),
(424, 'Vila Nova de Paiva', 20),
(425, 'Viseu', 20),
(426, 'Vouzela', 20);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `modalidade`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `modalidade` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `modalidade`
--

INSERT INTO `modalidade` (`id`, `nome`) VALUES
(1, 'Andebol'),
(2, 'Badminton'),
(3, 'Basket'),
(4, 'Futebol 11'),
(5, 'Futebol 7'),
(6, 'Futebol 6'),
(7, 'Futebol 5'),
(8, 'Futsal'),
(9, 'Jorkyball'),
(10, 'Padel'),
(11, 'Rugby'),
(12, 'Squash'),
(13, 'Tennis'),
(14, 'Voleibol');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `piso`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `piso` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tipo` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `piso`
--

INSERT INTO `piso` (`id`, `tipo`) VALUES
(1, 'Relvado Natural'),
(2, 'Relvado Sintético'),
(3, 'Campo de Areia'),
(4, 'Piso Sintético'),
(5, 'Parquet Flutuante');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `reservas`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reservas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_utilizador` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_disponibilidade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `n_posicoes_reservadas` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `preco` double NOT NULL,
  `codigo_promocional` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_socio` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_disponibilidade` (`id_disponibilidade`),
  KEY `id_utilizador` (`id_utilizador`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `reservas`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `utilizador`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `utilizador` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_socio` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `telefone` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `id_localidade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rua` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `codigo_postal` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `foto` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_localidade` (`id_localidade`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `utilizador`
--


--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `campo`
--
ALTER TABLE `campo`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `campo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_localidade`) REFERENCES `localidade` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `campo_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_piso`) REFERENCES `piso` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `campo_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_coberto`) REFERENCES `coberto` (`id`);

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `campo_fotos`
--
ALTER TABLE `campo_fotos`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `campo_fotos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_campo`) REFERENCES `campo` (`id`);

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `campo_gestor`
--
ALTER TABLE `campo_gestor`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `campo_gestor_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_gestor`) REFERENCES `gestor` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `campo_gestor_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_campo`) REFERENCES `campo` (`id`);

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `campo_modalidade`
--
ALTER TABLE `campo_modalidade`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `campo_modalidade_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_campo`) REFERENCES `campo` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `campo_modalidade_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_modalidade`) REFERENCES `modalidade` (`id`);

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `clube`
--
ALTER TABLE `clube`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `clube_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_localidade`) REFERENCES `localidade` (`id`);

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `clube_gestor`
--
ALTER TABLE `clube_gestor`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `clube_gestor_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_clube`) REFERENCES `clube` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `clube_gestor_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_gestor`) REFERENCES `gestor` (`id`);

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `disponibilidade_campo`
--
ALTER TABLE `disponibilidade_campo`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `disponibilidade_campo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_campo`) REFERENCES `campo` (`id`);

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `gestor`
--
ALTER TABLE `gestor`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `gestor_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_localidade`) REFERENCES `localidade` (`id`);

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `localidade`
--
ALTER TABLE `localidade`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `localidade_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_distrito`) REFERENCES `distrito` (`id`);

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `reservas`
--
ALTER TABLE `reservas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `reservas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_utilizador`) REFERENCES `utilizador` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `reservas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_disponibilidade`) REFERENCES `disponibilidade_campo` (`id`);

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `utilizador`
--
ALTER TABLE `utilizador`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utilizador_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_localidade`) REFERENCES `localidade` (`id`);
```

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Well, you've got a UTF-8 page and a bunch of Latin1 columns. But since you don't show the PHP where you actually write anything to the database, it's impossible to guess how you're trying to reconcile these facts.

Answer (score 0):

Often special characters are a problem of translation and can get lost unless you use utf-8 to maintain them across all your data/communication lines. There are a few items that could help.  Sometiles it helps to set the web page to utf-8 explicitly:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Also sometimes you need to set the database connection to be utf-8 as well:

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8 ");
```

If you have these set and the data still looks garbles in the database, you may need to change the character set ont he table, or perhaps the coolation.